# Postgres change password for dblink automatically

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, amazon-aurora

I'm migrating an Oracle database to Postgres 11.5 version on AWS where there are some functions that will capture logs in a table with Oracle pragma autonomous transaction since the application will rollback the database in case of exceptions.

Since the only option i could find for doing this in postgres is using dblink extension(pg_background extension is not supported in AWS), I created a dblink where source and target databases are same. I'll commit the inserts using dblink from a function that is called inside exception blocks.

How can I hide the password from the code without storing it in server side? And if the database instance password is changed how can I handle it? Because i would need to change the password for dblink everytime when it is reset.

Any ways to get/pass the instance password dynamically inside the code?

Comment: You could use a [.pgpass file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)

Comment: as mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name this would be the way to go..